# How to use bundled js file generated by webpack inside typescript or javascript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am working on application that already build in angular. I want to remove it angular dependencies to use every platform like(react, angular, simple js etc). Reason behind to use Webpack is I have to install @microsoft/signalr node package .Webpack provide functionality to install node modules and bundled all typescript file into single js file.I succesfully compiled all typescript file to bundled js file. **If I used budled js file inside html it worked fine.  Now the problem is that when I import bundled js file inside typescript it will give error "export is not defined" after compile to js.**

**Here is my code that bundled my all typescript file to single js file**

**tsconfig.json file**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "Unit_Tests"
  ]
}
```

**web.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports =  {
    entry:"./src/app/index.ts",
    mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'JSApi.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    

  },
};
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "source",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=development --watch",
    "release": "webpack --mode=production",
    "publish": "npm run release && dotnet publish -c Release"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "6.7.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.7.5",
    "ts-loader": "9.4.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.2",
    "typescript": "5.0.2",
    "webpack": "5.76.3",
    "webpack-cli": "5.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.4",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.10"
  }
}
```

**Typescript Class1 and Class2 code**

```
export class Class1{
// Here is my code
}

export class Class2{
// Here is my code
}
```

*Here is my code where I want to import bundle js file but i was unable to import it will return error like*
**export is not define**
for resolving this error I add this line inside html head tag
**var exports = {};**
Then it give **require is not define**

```
import {
    Class1, Class2
} from './JSApi.js'
```